# FirebaseMLVisionTextModel has been deprecated in favor of MLKitTextRecognition

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit

I am using Firebase MLKit TextRecognition API. There is a warning when trying to update **'pod Firebase/MLVisionTextModel'**. How to update Firebase MLKit library?

> [!] FirebaseMLVisionTextModel has been deprecated in favor of MLKitTextRecognition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase on-device APIs have moved under [GoogleMLKit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/).

> On June 3, 2020, we made some changes to ML Kit for Firebase to better distinguish the on-device APIs from cloud based APIs. The current set of APIs is now split into the following two products:
>
> - A new product, simply called ML Kit, which will contain all the on-device APIs
> - Firebase Machine Learning, focused on cloud-based APIs and custom model deployment.

So the new version of `Firebase/MLVisionTextModel` is `GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition`

```
pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition'
```

There is also a [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration) to the new API.

Comment: This doesn't work for flutter, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66342152/specs-satisfying-the-googlemlkit-textrecognition-dependency-were-found-but-th/66342534?noredirect=1#comment117398099_66342534