# Flutter - Specs satisfying the `GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target

Tags: ios, flutter, google-mlkit

I have a flutter app

I added `pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition'` to my pod file, and did `pod install`

I get the error
`Specs satisfying the` GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition `dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.`

I would like to know:

1. What is the `minimum deployment target`?
2. How do I set it?

EDIT:

According to Dong Chen comment, here is my Podfile:

```js
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition'
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    # Can be removed when moving to cocoapods 1.10
    config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_QUOTED_INCLUDE_IN_FRAMEWORK_HEADER'] = 'NO'
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)

    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # Inherit the deployment target defined in this Podfile instead, e.g. platform :ios, '11.0' at the top of this file
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this error by setting `platform :ios, '10.0'` at the top of the pos file.

But when I do `pod install` I get `[!] FirebaseMLVision has been deprecated`

Comment: Can you share you Podfile?  `FirebaseML` is now deprecated.  It's now replaced by `GoogleMLKit`.  Please see the migration guide here: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration?hl=en .  And specific instructions for iOS is here: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/ios?hl=en .  Please also check out the Podfile of the quickstart sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/ios/quickstarts/vision/Podfile .

Comment: @Dong Chen please see the Podfile in the Question part, thanks.
NOTE: there is no reference to `Firebase` or `FirebaseMLVision` in the Podfile at all.

Comment: Your Podfile contains a lot of other stuffs in addition to `pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition'`.  For example, it has `flutter_ios_podfile_setup` and `flutter_install_all_ios_pods` which are not defined directly within this Podfile, so I have no idea what they do.  Since the new `GoogleMLKit` does not support flutter, could those flutter-related steps pull in the `FirebaseMLVision` (part of the legacy `FirebaseML` which did support flutter, but we no longer support)? And you shouldn't mix the legacy `FirebaseML` flutter with the new `GoogleMLKit`.

Comment: If I remove all the other lines and keep only:
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!
project 'VisionExample.xcodeproj'
target 'VisionExample' do
end
target 'VisionExampleObjc' do
end
pod 'GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition'.  Then the cocoapod can be installed without issues.

Comment: 'new GoogleMLKit does not support flutter', is that real? My app is flutter, what am I supposed to do than?

Comment: I guess that you might be able to try use the deprecated `FirebaseML`, so instead of `GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition` cocopoad, you could try add `Firebase/MLVision` and `Firebase/MLVisionTextModel` cocoapods. However, again, please note that the legacy `FirebaseML` is deprecated and no longer supported.