# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly" on React Native ios

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to install [React Native Firebase Mlkit](https://github.com/mateuscgs/react-native-firebase-mlkit) to my existing iOS React Native app. My app is already using various Firebase packages (app, auth, firestore, etc.).

I am following the instructions from the guide. I tried both automatic and manual installation. But when I run `pod install`, I got this error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
  In Podfile:
    Firebase/MLVisionTextModel was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 5.0.0)

    RNFBApp (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app`) was resolved to 14.3.0, which depends on
      Firebase/CoreOnly (= 8.11.0)
```

This is my POD File:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'com.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false
  )

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
  pod 'Firebase/MLVisionTextModel'
  pod 'Firebase/MLVisionBarcodeModel'

  target 'com.xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
    pod 'react-native-splash-screen', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-splash-screen'

    pod 'react-native-receive-sharing-intent', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-receive-sharing-intent'

    pod 'RNMlKit', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase-mlkit/ios'

  end

  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable the next line.
  use_flipper!()

  post_install do |installer|
    react_native_post_install(installer)
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end
```

This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxxxxxxx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dudigital/react-native-zoomable-view": "^1.1.3",
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.1.5",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.14",
    "@react-native-community/cli": "^6.3.1",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^14.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^14.3.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^7.0.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
    "i18n-js": "^3.8.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.66.4",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^7.1.2",
    "react-native-eject": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-firebase-mlkit": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^4.6.0",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-receive-sharing-intent": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-share": "^7.3.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-vision-camera": "^2.12.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

There are a lots of similiar question here, but nothing works. This is a list of various commands I tried in different orders:

- deleted Pods folder
- `rm -rf Podfile.lock`
- `pod update`
- `pod repo update`
- `pod install --repo-update`
- Remove `pod 'Firebase/Core'` from the pod file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** First off `Firebase/MLVisionTextModel` is deprecated  ([FirebaseMLVisionTextModel has been deprecated in favor of MLKitTextRecognition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63573344/firebasemlvisiontextmodel-has-been-deprecated-in-favor-of-mlkittextrecognition)). You can read the migration guide here (https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration)

**2)** If you ever have errors like `was resolved to x.x.x, which depends on Firebase/CoreOnly (= x.x.x)` A lot of times you can fix this by adding this below at the very top of your PodFile to specify what version to use.

```
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '8.10.0'
```