# Can't run app in simulator using FirebaseMLCommon.framework/FirebaseMLCommon in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using Xcode Version 14.0.1 (14A400) & Mac OS Monterey 12.6 &

```
pod 'Firebase/MLVision'
pod 'Firebase/MLVisionTextModel'
```

When I run the app on the real device it works fine. When I run on the simulator it shows the below error:

```
error build: In../Pods/FirebaseMLCommon/Frameworks/FirebaseMLCommon.framework/FirebaseMLCommon(aligned_new_bca0ac320467a2457b3e306bfed17856.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Volumes/Mydocument/Workspace/IOS/Runnig/bcbl-ios-app/Pods/FirebaseMLCommon/Frameworks/FirebaseMLCommon.framework/FirebaseMLCommon' for architecture arm64
```

Please help to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

First, is your mac apple silicon CPU type or intel CPU type?

Not all 3rd party dependencies work on iOS simulators. You have to understand the architecture for a real iOS device is usually `arm64`. However, the simulator's architecture is `Simulator-x86_64` on an intel mac and `Simulator-arm64` on an apple silicon mac. So unless google provides you with a fat universal version of it, you cannot build it for simulators.

So, you can try to exclude the `Simulator-arm64` arch in Xcode as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63607158/xcode-building-for-ios-simulator-but-linking-in-an-object-file-built-for-ios-f).

BTW, if it does not work, another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63573344/firebasemlvisiontextmodel-has-been-deprecated-in-favor-of-mlkittextrecognition) points out that the `MLVisionTextModel` is deprecated. Consider migrating to the new pod.
Cause in the new pod `GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition,` I have seen the below code in its podfile. So I guess it supports x86_64 simulators.

```
  "pod_target_xcconfig": {
   "EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]": "arm64"
   },
```